# React-Saga Effects

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

It might be a silly Question to ask, but I am pretty confused about Redux-Saga Effects, What's the actual Role of Redux-Saga Effects, I went through documents, but there is hell of complexity to understand it. I want to know what is the exact role of every effect, like put, take, takeEvery, takeLatest, etc, I want to learn which one to use at which occasion, I will be appreciated for any simple and detailed answer other than Documentation of React-Saga.

Comment: How familiar are you with Redux itself?  Specifically, dispatching actions?

Comment: i am new to react , just trying new stuffs, i know how redux work with any middlewear and i know to the basic flow of redux-saga i mean it's work, but don't know the exact difference between all the types of effects, that's what i want to learn

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the docs can be too technical and not really give a good example of their purpose.  You might try reading this.  https://programmersought.com/article/95693396065/

Comment: Yoo Men!, Thanks, Can you put to the answer, so every learner like me Check this and save their time instead of reading useless Docs!

Comment: You're talking about [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) (22k stars), not [React-Saga](https://github.com/barbuza/react-saga) (depends on Redux-Saga, 4 stars), right?

Comment: Redux-saga, just Updated the Question, and I already get an answer.